# SQL Exception block gets entered though it shouldn't

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

I'm having a procedure in SQL where I'm reading from an input list and inserting into a table and giving back a list of same type, which consists of all records for which there had been some exception while inserting the data into table.
Below is the code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST IN EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST, o_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST OUT EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST) AS 

BEGIN

  FOR i in 1..i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST.COUNT
    LOOP
      BEGIN
         For Process_Name In(
      Select P.Extt_Process_sid, P.Execute_For_Sub_Portfolio_Ind From Extt_Process P 
      Where 
      P.Extt_Acc_Region_Cd=i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i).Extt_Acc_Region_Cd And 
      P.Extt_Time_Period_View_Cd=i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i).Extt_Time_Period_View_Cd
      )
        Loop
        BEGIN
        If (i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i).extt_SubPortfolio_Ind = 'Y' And Process_Name.Execute_For_Sub_Portfolio_Ind = 'N') = FALSE Then
          Insert Into Extt_Process_Execution Pe(
            Pe.Extt_Process_Exec_Sid,
            Pe.Extt_Process_sid, 
            Pe.Extt_Process_Exec_Start_Ts,
            Pe.Extt_Portfolio_Id,
            Pe.Extt_Process_Exec_Status_Cd,
            Pe.Report_From_Dt,
            Pe.Report_To_Dt,
            Pe.Created_By_Id,
            Pe.Created_Ts,
            UPDATED_BY_ID,
            UPDATED_TS)
            Values(
            Apex_De_Seq.Nextval,
            Process_name.extt_process_sid,
            i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i).Extt_Process_Exec_Start_Ts,
            i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i).Extt_Portfolio_Id,
            i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i).Extt_Process_Exec_Status_Cd,
            i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i).Report_From_Dt,
            i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i).Report_To_Dt,
            user,
            Systimestamp,
            user,
            Systimestamp
            );

        END IF;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN others then

            IF o_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST IS NULL THEN
            o_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST:=EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i));

            ELSE

          o_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST.extend();

          o_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(o_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST.count):=i_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST(i);
          END IF;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(o_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST.count);
        END;
        End Loop;
      END;
      END LOOP;
END TEST;
```

The DBMS output for this is 1, even though the record i inserted was perfect and wouldn't cause any exception. I believe the way I'm handling the exception or the scoping of the block is messed up. Please help!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `EXCEPTION WHEN` subblock? Does it throw an exception then?

Comment: No, it doesn't. There is supposed to be no exception. I've written the exception block just in case there is an exception, it should handle it gracefully.

Comment: What is the purpose of parameter o_EXTRACTION_TYPE_LIST? Your exception block will only catch errors, regarding tables columns validation(types,length). I presume, you wan't to catch exception, when there is no data to insert? By the way, your insert statement can be easily be written in one "insert into .. select"structure - that is you can put your collection in Table(collection) form and treat it as a table.

Comment: For solution, could you provide some sample data with scenario (expected end result) and the types DDL?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you *shouldn't* be entering your exception block, but you are, so there must be some sort of exception happening. Add `dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm)` to your exception block to determine what is happening. There are too many possibilities about what could be going wrong to speculate.